# Sweet Alert and ajax calls based on id on php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert

I have a php page with a php while loop in which i get user details along with id. The loop creates buttons which when clicked i need to know the details of each used based on their ID as in image below.

http://tinypic.com/r/znl8w9/9

```
<td><button class='btn btn-success' value="<?php echo $id ;?>" onclick="javascript:getDetails();">View Details</button></td>
```

I need to display the details in a javascript sweetalert modal window.

```js
function getDetails() {
  swal({
    title: "User Details",
    text: User Details here!",
    confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4",
    imageUrl: "<?php echo $image; ?>"
  });
};
```

How can i get the details of each user id in the sweetalert modal by clicking on the loop generated buttons. Can we get the ID of each user via button and pass it to sweetalert and then do a ajax request to a different page and pull out details from database based on the ID and display it.

Or is there any other way to do it ??

Please is it possible? If so how ?? I am a newbie and sorry if i overlooked something.

Comment: It is not recommended to use id `detailsLink` more than once in the HTML.

Comment: @debute Oh! sorry... Forgot that it was a loop. Changed it. Is there any solution to this issue ??

Comment: sure it is, if you use jQuery, I can post a fast answer.

Comment: @debute Yep,,I do use JQuery in the page. Excited to know that a solution exists :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1, add a class to buttons, for example `user-details` and remove attribute `onclick`. Also add `data-*` attributes with your details, example:

```
<button class='btn btn-success user-details' data-name="John Doe 1" data-image="https://png.icons8.com/contacts/ios7/50/e67e22">View Details</button>
```

Step 2, bind an event handler to these buttons, note these attributes being used (you can add how many you want):

```
$('.user-details').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var image = $(this).attr('data-image');

    swal({
        title: "User Details",
        text: "User Details: " + name,
        confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4",
        imageUrl: image,
    });
});
```

This is pretty all you need, you can try a [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/m0s8c5jc/).

Comment: A better approach to get custom data attributes would be like this: `var name = $(this).data('name');`

Comment: I prefer using `attr` so it is obvious that I work with attribute, because when you set data with `$(this).data('name', 'foo');` then it will be saved to the node object not DOM, therefore `$(this).attr('data-name');` will output old data, which would be incorrect. But in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: @debute Thank you so much. That was an awesome solution without using ajax.. Learned so much from it. Thanking you once again for the great support.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to the `getDetails` function. something like:

```js
function getDetails(imageUrl, details1, details2) {
  swal({
    title: detail1,
    text: details2,
    confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4",
    imageUrl: imageUrl
  });
};
```

```html
<td>
  <button class='btn btn-success' value="<?php echo $id ;?>" onclick="getDetails('<?php $image ?>', '<?php details1 ?>', '<?php details2 ?>');">View Details</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. I need other details in other variables too other than image. Cant understand the imageUrl ???

Comment: @Pamela see my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Okay..I got the image working. I need other details too. Let me try the ajax solution too  by Latheesan

Comment: @Pamela you truly doesn't need an ajax. It will cause delay between user clicks and the tooltip displays for nothing.. You can move multiple params to the function. I was updated my answer..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax.

Firstly, change the way you render the buttons slightly like this:

```
<td>
    <button class='btn btn-success detailsLink' data-userId="<?php echo $id ?>">
        View Details
    </button>
</td>
```

Then handle the click event on the button with the class `.detailsLink` to invoke the ajax request to your backend, once you have the response render a html sweetalert like this:

```
// When document is ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Handle button click event
    $('button.detailsLink').click(function()
    {
        // Get user id from button
        var userId = $(this).data('userId');

        // Ajax request user details
        $.get('/user-details.php?userId=' + userId)
            .done(function(userData)
            {
                // Build html alert content
                var userInfo = '<p>User Name: '+ userData.userName +'</p>';
                userInfo += '<p>Age: '+ userData.age +'</p>';

                // Display html sweet alert
                swal({
                    title: 'Success',
                    html: userInfo,
                    type: 'info'
                });
            })
            .fail(function()
            {
                // Simple error handler
                swal('Oops...', 'Failed to load user info.', 'error');
            });
    });
});
```

And your backend script that provides the user data can be something like this:

```
<?php

// Parse user id
$userId = isset($_GET['userId']) ? $_GET['userId'] : 0;

// Run your sql query here to load user info
// I'm preparing dummy data here
$userData = array(
    'userName' => 'Bob',
    'age' => 39
);

// Send json response back
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($userData);
exit;
```

---

Alternatively; your backend script can generate the HTML and send it and your javascript can simply set it on sweet alert.

So, your backend script will look like this:

```
<?php

// Parse user id
$userId = isset($_GET['userId']) ? $_GET['userId'] : 0;

// Run your sql query here to load user info
// I'm preparing dummy data here
$userData = array(
    'userName' => 'Bob',
    'age' => 39
);

// Render html response

?>

<p>User Name: <?php echo $userData['userName'] ?></p>
<p>Age: <?php echo $userData['age'] ?></p>
```

And your ajax call will look like this:

```
// Ajax request user details
$.get('/user-details.php?userId=' + userId)
    .done(function(userDataHtml)
    {
        // Display html sweet alert
        swal({
            title: 'Success',
            html: userDataHtml,
            type: 'info'
        });
    })
    .fail(function()
    {
        // Simple error handler
        swal('Oops...', 'Failed to load user info.', 'error');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it.

Comment: userId is undefined in developer console for ajax request. Something seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `user details` as `function parameter`

```
`onclick="javascript:getDetails('<?php echo $title; ?>');"`
```

And Get it in Script

```
`function getDetails(title){
   swal({
   title: title,   // Getting title through Function parameter
   text: User Details here!",
   confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4",
   imageUrl: <?php echo $image; ?>"
  });
};`
```

Like this Get all `title`, `text`,`imageurl` like

```
`function(title,text,imageUrl){}`
```

Comment: Thanks. Okay..I got the image working. I need other details too. Let me try the ajax solution too  by Latheesan

Comment: `ajax` should increase your page load